# Bootstrap modal with youtube bug after hide on hover elements

Tags: graphics, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, modal-dialog

I use modal on my website to display youtube videos and all is working good.

But, when I start a video (then I stop it) and I close the modal, I have strange effects on my main menu that has a hover changing effects.

This is a sample video:
[image]

And then after closing and go with the mouse hover the menu this appears (on the 2 links that are "under" the modal):

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this bug?

**Additional info**

I am on Chrome and I have used a code very similar to the default example (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, putting

```
?wmode=opaque
```

at the end of the youtube url.